# Sleep at least vs sleep for at least

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Are both options valid? Or only one is?

Example sentence:

> From today, employees will be required to sleep (for) at least twenty minutes during lunch break.

I did a Google search. *Sleep at least* has more results. *Sleep for at least* has less results, but there are still there. So maybe both are valid but *for* is redundant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both valid. *For* is technically redundant, but a style guide may recommend using it. I consider the question of whether it is used or not to be a stylistic one.

Answer (score 0):

Both are valid, but for your sentance I would rather say:

> From today, employees will be required to take at least a twenty-minute nap during lunch break.

**edit** you can find below an other alternative suggested in the comments:

> Starting today, employees will be required to nap for at least twenty minutes during lunch break.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I updated the sentence to use "take a nap"

Comment: Well I don't agree with you on the "From today" part, and I opened a ticket for it in order to discuss it right there if you want to https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/198899/from-today-or-starting-today

However about the rest thank you for your feedback I updated the answer.

Comment: I think there is a misunderstanding here because as I told you before I appreciate your feedback and I updated my answer with your entire sentence.

Comment: Please feel free to directly add/change anything you want directly by using the "edit" button