# "From today" or "Starting today"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, adverbs

What is the difference between **From today** and **Starting today** ?

For instance in the following sentences:

> All users of Sitestat can download the
>   new toolbar free of charge from today.
>
> From today, employees will be required to take at least a twenty minutes nap during lunch break.
>
> Starting today, employees will be required to take at least a twenty minutes nap during lunch break.

Are they correct ?

Answer (score 1):

Some people might argue that ***from*** is ambiguous, and might or might not include *today*. However, I think this is not one of the ambiguous reference to time, myself (such as "by tomorrow"). I would read those as having identical meanings, and both are correct, standard, natural, and idiomatic.

Comment: "From today" sounds non-native to my ear.  Perhaps it's a matter of where one lives.

Comment: Never underestimate the importance of dialect. It's the same sense of *from* as *From Dusk till Dawn*.

Comment: "From Dusk till Dawn" is very different, though.  "From morning till night" is fine.  "From today", if it's not followed by "until", sounds to me like it should be "Starting today".  But again, perhaps English people speak this way, and after all, the English invented the language!

Comment: I wouldn't even assume it's all in England, we have enough dialects of our own to get confused by. I would think everyone in England would recognise both as valid, but likely many would choose one over the other in actual use. "From X 'till Y" is just "from X" and "until Y" put together, and both are well-attested on their own.

Comment: Let me clarify.  "From today until tomorrow" is fine.  "From today till tomorrow" is also fine.  But when I hear, "From today, we will ...", that sounds awkward.  It's almost as if I expect the "until" or "till" or "'til", and I feel a very slight disappointment when it doesn't come.  "Starting today", for some reason, doesn't cause this problem.

Comment: See, to me that just seems strange. It seems strange to me that it seems strange to you, so to speak. But that's what happens - not everyone who speaks the same language speaks the same language.